# how to import a submodule into my test module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I have a project structured as follows:

```
.
└── MYAPP/
    ├── data/ # contains data files i.e: html/json/db files.
    ├── src/
    │   └── myapp/
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── core.py
    │       └── utils.py
    └── tests/
        ├── conftest.py
        ├── test_core.py
        └── test_utils.py # contains ClassA and ClassB
```

`conftest.py` contains the following:

```py
import pytest
from src.myapp.utils import ClassA, ClassB
```

as you can see in the contents of `conftest.py`, I am importing the required classes using an absolute import.

By chance while reading through [Flask's](https://github.com/pallets/flask) source code on github, I saw that they were using a similar project structure:

```
.
└── flask/
    ├── src/
    │   └── flask
    └── tests
```

and in test files were not using absolute imports, for example in the `conftest.py` file they had the following:

```py
import pytest
from _pytest import monkeypatch

import flask
from flask import Flask as _Flask
```

My question is, How did flask achieve to import its module into `test` by just using `import flask` or `from flask import Flask as _Flask`. when I attempt to do that (`import myapp`), I end up with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'`

Comment: `Flask` (or any installed packages) are added to the `site-lib` in python. Your package is not part of this. Instead imports inside a project are either absolute or relative. More information about the import system is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Full scale blogs explaining it [here](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) and [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/). And on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: I might have misread your question, the above still provides a lot of information about the import system. But to be more precise to why you do not need `from src import flask` is because of their `__init__` file ([here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/__init__.py)) and their setup configurations ([here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/setup.cfg)), which make `src` the project root.

Comment: @Thymen , well in my `__init__.py` I have also included the main classes that I used in the test, the difference is the `setup.cfg` but I have also set the root package of my code using poetry instead.

Comment: If `src` is your project root, then you should be able to do `import myapp`, at least in my IDE (Pycharm) this would work.

Comment: @Thymen , I think the issue is like you said in the first comment, I didn't run the `poetry install` command that puts a link to `myapp` into the `site-lib`. Thank you for the links though, they were very informative.